# Is there an implementation of something like autotest-fsevent for windows?

Tags: windows, ruby, autotest

Basically it's an extension for autotest that listens for notification from OS and allows autotest not to scan for file changes permanently while testing only necessary changes. It saves CPU and disk use.

Answer (score 3):

Windows provides an API for File Change Notification called FindFirstChangeNotification 
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa365261(VS.85).aspx

It turns out that somebody already made a small ruby-bridge for this you might use for a starting point: 
http://blade.nagaokaut.ac.jp/cgi-bin/scat.rb/ruby/ruby-talk/36807

Answer (score 2):

There is [rb-fchange](https://rubygems.org/gems/rb-fchange) for [Guard](https://github.com/guard/guard).

Answer (score 0):

I tried several and in Vista [wdm](https://rubygems.org/gems/wdm) worked best for me.

```
require 'wdm'

monitor = WDM::Monitor.new
monitor.watch_recursively('c:\test') { |change|  puts change.path }
monitor.run!
```